# How to replace non-owned file in Android 13?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am working on application where I have to replace a file(image captured from camera) after editing it. Priorly I send request using Intent Sender to delete located at some URI and after that I save the image at that URI, but in Android 13 after deletion , when I open outputStream of deleted file to write new content It gives FileNotFoundException.

val intentSender = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, uriList).intentSender
deleteRequestResult.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build())

and onResultOfDelete

context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(outputUri, "wt")?.use { output ->
val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
var length: Int
while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0)
output.write(buffer, 0, length)
output.flush()
}

what when I openOutputStream it crashes and gives FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Ever heard of codeblocks? Please use them.

Comment: Do not delete the file first as you cannot use the url -the content scheme- to open an output stream for a file that does not exist.  Just overwrite the file.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about codeblocks and please provide some reference?

Comment: If I open outstream before deleting request it will give Security Exception

Comment: No. Not if you directly do it in onActivityResult. But you probably do it later.

Comment: Codeblocks? You only have to read some other posts to see how other posters post their code -readabke- in codeblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Android 11, apps can no longer access files outside their own app-specific directories by default. To fix this issue, you can use `ContentResolver.insert` to create a new file in your app's directory and get a new URI for that file